# Entity Framework infers relationship

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I have some code that is working, but I don't know how.  I'm asking this question in hopes that someone can explain how it is working, as any searching I do online gives me information that's not quite specific to what I'm seeing.

I have two entities.

EntityA, EntityB.

EntityA has this:

```
public partial class EntityA
{
    ...
    public Guid EntityBGuid { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
}
```

EntityB has this:

```
public partial class EntityB
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<EntityA> EntityAs{ get; set; }
}
```

Nowhere in `DatabaseEntities.cs > OnModelCreating()` is a relationship defined for either entity.

Nowhere in either table in SQL is there a FK defined for the relationship.

So when I do something like this:

```
context.LettingProjects.Where(query).Select(s => s.Call).ToList(); //Crash.
```

But with a .Include, I get data:

```
context.LettingProjects.Include(i => i.Call).Where(query).Select(s => s.Call).ToList(); //Results.
```

My question is how does this even work?  I don't know how EF handles this in the background, and it seems like a gotcha waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are writing this:

```cs
context.LettingProjects.Where(query).Select(s => s.Call).ToList();
```

EF will simply query for a single table.

However, as you probably configured the relationships in your models to contain other Tables too (`ICollection<EntityA>`), they will contain a `null` value because EF will not send a query asking for their data.

> My question is, how does this even work? I don't know how EF handles this in the background, and it seems like a gotcha waiting to happen.

The answer to your question now should be simple:
when you write `.Include(s => s.OtherTable)` you are asking EF to join your current table data with the one you specified.

EF will use the Foreign Key relationships and will give you back a collection of items with the data for the related tables, too (not null version). That's why it will not fail.

---

This is very similar to using the LINQ to Entities `Join` method, but in this case, it's requiring you to write much less code unless you want to control the join operation by yourself.

Comment: So with no fk, or relationship defined outside the virtual keyword, EF somehow knows that EntityBGuid on EntityA is the right value to use for the join into EntityA?  Or am I still misunderstanding here?

Comment: @Adola EF knows that `EntityA` can be joined with `EntityB` only if you are defining their relations in your model as you did in your above example. If you do not define their relationships, you should see the error when trying to use the `Include` method. So, EF sees that they are connected when you define `ICollection<EntityB>` inside `EntityA`, and then when you try using the `Include` method, EF will check their Foreign Key relations and join them if the tables in behind are really connected, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: Ok, so that helps clear something up for me then, I didn't realize that EF treated the virtual Collection and Object as a relationship, and I think I can safely assume then that EF makes an educated guess that 
`public Guid EntityBGuid { get; set; }` likely correlates to `public virtual EntityB EntityB { get; set; }` based on the name of the property `EntityBGuid `

Comment: @Adola, exactly. Frankly, you always need to define your EF model correctly, matching the real table Columns, or if not you can still use attributes to do that, but that's another story. And EF always needs for the table to contain PK in order to work with collections.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, I knew something 'magic' was happening, and that explains it.